# customize initWithNibName

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, initialization

I want to have a custom `initWithNibName`, basically passing in another `NSString` as a type to determine some logic inside this `UIViewController` based on the type. So I set is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andFeedType:(NSString *)feedType
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Does this even make sense? As I don't see this type of init's quite often. If not then what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes perfectly sense to me. This is the way you would override an initializer to add some custom initialization in Objective-C. What do you think is wrong with it ?

Comment: I just never saw an initWithNibName customized, that's all. I thought this was a wrong pattern to do it

Answer (score 2):

Yes it makes sense. In addition, if you want to keep clean your init you could do the following:

```
- (id)initWithFeedType:(NSString *)feedType
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil]; // nil is ok if the nib is included in the main bundle
    if (self) {

        // Set your feed here (copy it since you are using a string)

        // see the edit
        myFeedType = [feedType copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

For further info see the post [initWithNibName-bundle-breaks-encapsulation](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/01/initWithNibName-bundle-breaks-encapsulation/) by **Ole Begemann.**

Hope that helps.

**Edit**

If that feed property cannot be accessed by external objects, create a class extension for your controller like the following:

```
//.m
@interface YourController ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* myFeedType;

@end

@implementation YourController

@synthesize myFeedType;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

It does make sense. You are creating you own initializer, tailored to your needs. Also, you are doing what you should, which is calling the designated initializer (in the case of `UIViewController` `initWithNibName:bundle:`) inside your custom init method.

Answer (score 0):

Wait!
There is one reason why it may not be best: this method is **not** called when your view controller is loaded from a storyboard. For this reason I recommend using `viewDidLoad:` instead for the custom logic, and setting your custom string as a property.